# TM4C123 development board issue

Tags: microcontroller, debugging

I have started using a TM4C123GXL development board with Keil uVision as the programmer / debugger. I have wrote the attached simple code (see below) to become familiar with using the debugger to see what the MCU is doing in memory.

[image]

When I compile and run in simulator, my code won't let me step through the simulation, appearing to be stuck on line 602 as shown below.

[image]

I am unsure what the PLL is locked means and what is the cause for this?

***EDIT***

I have a question based on the link from Tyler's answer below. What should I download from this list?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You have not setup the system clock, TI has a ton of resources called TivaWare, [link](http://www.ti.com/tool/SW-TM4C). And their own IDE called Code Composer Studio. All free.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a lot, to start with you need the following:

```
//
// Run from the PLL at 120 MHz.
//
g_ui32SysClock = MAP_SysCtlClockFreqSet((SYSCTL_XTAL_25MHZ |
SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN | SYSCTL_USE_PLL |
SYSCTL_CFG_VCO_480), 120000000);
```

Also, the Tiva Ware package has a ton of resources, documentation, sample programs, etc etc. Including a "Hello World" bare minimum program.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, but I have another question for you. See my edited question above if you don't mind helping.

Comment: @David777 It depends on what you are planning on doing, obviously the "full release" is everything, that would be all the different TM4C board and peripheral board. You can pick and choose in the software & libraries section, but if you are not sure which you will need, I would just get the full release.

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I will download the full release if I can get an account created for Texas Instruments which is proving very difficult. I will get back to this thread if I have any more queries. Thanks again for your help.